# How to redirect page from http to htpps with url name change

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have the following problem

I need two things:

1. Redirect from unsafe HTTP to safe HTTPS and then
2. Redirect from `https://example.com/index.html` to `https://example.com/work-for-us`

I know the first one I can obtain using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and the second one using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule work-for-us index.html
```

But is it possible to connect those two together?

So I have both HTTP -> HTTPS and /index.html -> /work-for-us

I don't have too much knowledge about .htaccess file, I read something on the internet but didn't find anything that answers my question.

So putting everything together, I want to change the URL from this:

`http://example.com/index.html` to this `https://example.com/work-for-us`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, so it means you are hitting link `http://example.com/index.html` in browser? And want it to change in browser to `https://example.com/work-for-us`? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: i enter the website from google, and it hits https: //example.com
(because i used the rewrite rule from HTTP to HTTPS). The file on the server that is loaded is index.html. So what appear in URL bar is https: //example.com.
But answering your question - if anybody writes what you wrote then yes, I want them to be redirected to what you wrote @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
##First rule for applying https to URLs.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

##Second rule for serving homepage(only dns link) with index.html file.
RewriteRule ^/?$ work-for-us [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.html [L]

##Third rule for serving non-existing directories/files with index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```